# reorder columns after cte in sql

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I need the results of this to be unchanged but i want it to reorder the columns to a specific order.  The order i want is Due Beyond, Due Monday, Due Tomorrow, Due Today, Past Due

can anyone help with this

```
with cte AS (SELECT cl.Name,

SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.TruncateDate(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = dbo.TruncateDate(oi.RequiredByDate) THEN 1 Else 0 END) as DueToday
,SUM(CASE WHEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > oi.RequiredByDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as PastDue
,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, oi.RequiredByDate), 0) = dateadd(day, datediff(day, '19000101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'19000102') then 1 ELSE 0 END) as DueTomorrow
,SUM(CASE WHEN DateDiff(day, getdate(), RequiredByDate) BETWEEN 2 and 7 AND DateName(weekday, RequiredByDate) = 'Monday' Then 1 ELSE 0 END) as DueMonday
,SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.TruncateDate(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) <= dbo.TruncateDate(oi.RequiredByDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as DueBeyond


FROM OrderItems oi
JOIN Orders o ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
JOIN Counties c ON c.FIPS = o.FIPS
JOIN Clients cl ON cl.ClientID = o.ClientID
JOIN Milestones m ON m.MilestoneID = oi.LastMilestoneID
JOIN Products p ON p.ProductID = oi.ProductID
JOIN Vendors v ON v.VendorID = oi.VendorID
LEFT JOIN ClientBranches clb ON clb.ClientID = o.ClientID
WHERE QueueID > 0 AND cl.Name NOT LIKE 'TES%'
AND cl.NAME LIKE 'HLC%'
GROUP BY cl.Name 


)

Select * FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the order of the `SELECT` clause.

```
with cte AS (SELECT cl.Name

,SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.TruncateDate(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) <= dbo.TruncateDate(oi.RequiredByDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
as DueBeyond
,SUM(CASE WHEN DateDiff(day, getdate(), RequiredByDate) BETWEEN 2 and 7 AND DateName(weekday, RequiredByDate) = 'Monday' Then 1 ELSE 0 END) 
as DueMonday
,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, oi.RequiredByDate), 0) = dateadd(day, datediff(day, '19000101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'19000102') then 1 ELSE 0 END)
as DueTomorrow
,SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.TruncateDate(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = dbo.TruncateDate(oi.RequiredByDate) THEN 1 Else 0 END) 
as DueToday
,SUM(CASE WHEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > oi.RequiredByDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
as PastDue

FROM OrderItems oi
JOIN Orders o ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
JOIN Counties c ON c.FIPS = o.FIPS
JOIN Clients cl ON cl.ClientID = o.ClientID
JOIN Milestones m ON m.MilestoneID = oi.LastMilestoneID
JOIN Products p ON p.ProductID = oi.ProductID
JOIN Vendors v ON v.VendorID = oi.VendorID
LEFT JOIN ClientBranches clb ON clb.ClientID = o.ClientID
WHERE QueueID > 0 AND cl.Name NOT LIKE 'TES%'
AND cl.NAME LIKE 'HLC%'
GROUP BY cl.Name 


)

Select * FROM cte
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `Select * FROM cte` with

```
Select DueBeyond, DueMonday, DueTomorrow, DueToday, PastDue
 from cte
```

Comment: this worked but did not include the cl.name columnn, no worries though i didnt specify i needed it

Answer (score 1):

In your select:

`SELECT DueBeyond, DueMonday, DueTomorrow, DueToday, PastDue FROM cte`